# How can I draw polyline Between two location in Google Map using Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I try to draw polyline between two locations on google map in android as shown in the image I try to draw polyline between two locations on google map in android as shown in the image how can I draw this?

[image: correct image]
but I cannot draw perfect how can I draw it

I try below code but it's not working

**here is my code:**

```
public void mSetUpMap() {
googleMap.clear();

if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
    str = AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary();
if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
    shareUrl = AppUtil.itinerary.getShareUrl();
Log.e("Ittt", "" + AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary());
((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setTexrViewText(str);
poiList.clear();
poiList = AppUtil.itinerary.getPoiList();
List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<>();

for (POI item: poiList) {
    Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude()))
            .title(item.getName()).anchor(0.39f, 0.39f)

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCustomMarker
((R.drawable.m2red), item.getName()))));
  }
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); 
        ani.setDuration(2000);
        ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        ani.start();
        return true;
    }
 });
 /**create for loop for get the latLngbuilder from the marker list*/
 builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
 for (Marker m : markersList) {
    builder.include(m.getPosition());
 }
 int padding = 200;
 LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
 cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
  googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        /**set animated zoom camera into map*/
        googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        for (POI item : poiList) {
            polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), 
     item.getLongitude()));
        }
        polylineOptions.width(3);
        polylineOptions.getPoints();
        polylineOptions.getPoints();
        polylineOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
     }
   });
 }
```

Comment: can you post the log errror?

Comment: I do not get any error in logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change this code:

```
Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude()))
        .title(item.getName()).anchor(0.6f, 0.7f)
```

.anchor() method is work